# How to use $setIntersection with a non-array data type in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use $setIntersection to compare a string data type (heroName) and 2 arrays (heroOptions and heroChoosen) to get the object _id of the same values of those three fields. I do not want to use the $expr operator but only the $setIntersection. The problem I am running into is that $setIntersection only compares arrays, and game is a string data type.

```
Document 1:
_id:ObjectId("111111111111111111112")
heroName:"Batman"
heroOptions:"Batman"
            "Superman"
            "Robin"
heroChoosen:"Batman"
            "The Flash"
```

Document 1 contains similar value (Batman) in heroName, heroOptions, and heroChoosen so then the _id would be displayed of document 1.

Comment: You really mean [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/). i.e `{ $in: [ "$heroName", "$heroOptions" ] }` where the first argument is the expression ( "string" ) to match and the second is the array. Alternately `{ $setIntersection: [["$heroName"], "$heroOptions"] }` as a "hacky" way to wrap the single element as an array.

Comment: Thank you for the replay back Neil, when you used the {$setIntersection:[["$heroName"], "$heroOptions"]} would this be possible to use since heroName is still a string data type and not an array. Sorry for any confusion, I am trying to grasp this new concept.

Comment: Follow up, I think I do understand why you did ["$heroName"], so this basically turns the String value into an array like you mentioned?